# Limit of $\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}$ in degrees

Tags: calculus, limits

What does $\lim \limits_{\theta\to0}\dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}$ equal when $\theta$ is expressed in degrees?

I know that theta in degrees is $\frac{\pi}{180}$ theta radians, but I don't get the final answer of $0.01745$.

Comment: Have you studied l'hopitals rule?

Comment: Yes, but I know that I can do this without the l'hospitals rule.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Using L'H to calculate a derivative is circular logic.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\sin\theta^\circ}{\theta^\circ} = \lim_{\theta\to0} \frac{\sin\left( \dfrac{\pi\theta}{180}\text{ radians} \right)}{\theta} = \lim_{\eta\to0} \frac{\sin(\eta\text{ radians})}{\left( \dfrac{180\eta}{\pi} \right)} = \frac\pi{180}\lim_{\eta\to0} \frac{\sin\eta}{\eta}.
$$

This is why radians are used: When radians are used then $\lim\limits_{\eta\to0} \dfrac{\sin \eta} \eta=1$.

**Postscript in response to comments below:**

The question is how to find
\begin{align}
& \lim_{\theta\to0} \frac{\text{sine of $\theta$ degrees}}\theta = \lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\text{sine function in radians}\left(\dfrac{\pi\theta}{180}\right)} \theta \\[12pt]
= {} & \frac\pi{180}\lim_{\theta\to0} \frac{\text{sine function in radians}\left(\dfrac{\pi\theta}{180}\right)} {\dfrac{\pi\theta}{180}} = \frac\pi{180}\lim_{\eta\to0} \frac{\text{sine function in radians}(\eta)}\eta.
\end{align}

In other words the notation "$\sin$" means a particular function: the one that maps a number $\eta$ to the sine of $\eta$ radians.

**End of postscript**

It's the same as the reason why $e$ is the "natural" base for exponential functions:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} 2^x & = (2^x\cdot\text{constant}) \\[10pt]
\frac{d}{dx} 3^x & = (3^x\cdot\text{a different consant}) \\[10pt]
\frac{d}{dx} 20^x & = (20^x\cdot\text{yet another constant})
\end{align}
etc.  Only when the base is $e$ is the "constant" equal to $1$.

Comment: What I don't understand is the first equality.  The original denominator is theta in degrees.  So in the first equality, why is the denominator just theta but not (pi theta/180 radians)?  Should we convert it to radians as well like the way we did for sin in the numerator?

Comment: @abc : I've expanded the answer in response to your comment above. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

The questions seems to be asking you to evaluate

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^*(x)}{x},$$

where $\sin^*$ means the usual $\sin$ function but evaluating its argument in terms of degrees.

Now, since $360^\circ = 2\pi$ radians, we have the identity

$$\sin^*(x) = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{360}\right)$$

(This is worth contemplating for a bit)

Anyway, we now are trying to evaluate

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\frac{2\pi x}{360})}{x}$$

Applying L'Hopital, this is equal to the limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2\pi}{360} \frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi x}{360})}{1} = \frac{2\pi}{360} \sim 0.01745.$$

Comment: I think the question is asking that if the denominator x is in degrees as well.  When you write "x" as the denominator, do you mean "x" in degrees or "x" in radians?  That is the part that I am the most confused about.

Comment: So I think the problem is worded in an unfortunate way. You really shouldn't think of the denominator as being degrees or radians... what would it mean to divide by 5 degrees? So when I write $x$ I just mean the real number $x$. The difference comes when I want to take $sin$ of $x$. After all, it doesn't really make sense to take $sin$ of a number, but rather $sin$ of an angle. So I have to decide how to turn a real number $x$ into an angle. One way I can do that is with radians, where $\pi/2$ gets mapped to a right angle. Another way is with degrees, where $90$ gets mapped to a right angle.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the limit in radians $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$$ then the limit, with $x$ given in degrees is
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin \frac{\pi x}{180}}{x} = \frac{\pi}{180}\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin \frac{\pi x}{180}}{\frac{\pi x}{180}}$$

Comment: Why don't we need to convert the denominator "x" to "pi time x divided by 180" as well?

Comment: Because $x$ is just a number. However, the argument of $\sin$ is considered to be in radians. If the number we have is in degrees, we must adjust it.

Comment: In my original question (in the calculus book), "x" actually is written as "x^0c" (i.e. x is in degrees).  So shouldn't I convert x^0c to x times pi/180 rad as in the numerator?

Comment: No. Degrees (or radians) are dimensionless. Outside of a trigonometric function, they are just numbers.

Comment: An alternative explanation is that if you draw the unit circle and a radius, calling $x$ the arc length of the sector thus created between the positive $x$-axis and the radius. Then, the angle in radians of the sector is $x$. Dropping a perpendicular from the point of intersection of the radius and the circle, we draw a line of length $\sin x$. If we now decide to label the same angle in degrees, we get the angle to be $\frac{180x}{\pi}$, $\textbf{but the lengths of the arc and the perpendicular are unchanged}$.

Answer (score 0):

When angles are said to be in degrees, this actually means that when applying trigonometric functions, they are interpreted as degrees. Hence in the question "$\sin(\theta)$" must be understood as $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi\theta}{180}\right)$$ where $\sin$ is the usual sine function (arguments in radians) and you are in fact computing

$$\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi\theta}{180}\right)}\theta.$$

There is no reason to convert at the denominator, division is still the ordinary division. Only the trigonometric function is "special".

Answer (score -2):

The question is not properly posed.

In whatever units the is angle chosen the result is the same $(=1).$

For all units (degree, radian)

$$ lim_{X \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin X}{X}$$

equals unity.

You should get that answer independently  when asked " how many radians are there in a degree?"

Comment: In a way I agree. On the other hand, the question implies that when taking the sine, angles are interpreted as degrees. Hence, $\sin(1)/1=0.0174524...$, not $0.84147...$

Comment: Evaluating a fraction when the denominator is still kept at $1$..  when argument of numerator and the denominator  should together tend to zero...that to me appears as needing some correction.

Comment: Come on, I am not computing the limit, I am showing which sine you need to consider.